# Ruby array delete vs delete(bang)

Tags: ruby, arrays

I thought Array#delete deleted all copies of an object in an array, but some weird (and inexplicable to me) things are happening in this program I am writing.  Delete only seems to work when I include a bang at the end of the delete function, even though that doesn't seem to be defined.

Here is the function in question:

```
  def propagate
    @puzzle.each do |sqr, values|
      if values.length == 1
        @neighbors[sqr].each do |neighbor|
          @puzzle[neighbor].delete!(values)
        end 
      end 
    end 
  end
```

@puzzle is a hash with strings as keys and values, formatted like so: `@puzzle["A1"] = "123456789"`

@neighbors is a hash with strings as keys and arrays of strings as values:

```
@neighbors["A1"] = ["A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "I1", "B2", "B3", "C2", "C3"]
```

when I run the code like this:  `@puzzle[neighbor].delete(values)`

The values in puzzle are unaffected by the delete.  But when I include the ! it works.

Why is this?

Comment: The thing is in IRB i tried duplicating the scenario, and the interpreter doesn't even recognize `delete!`.  Also, the regular delete mutates the array as expected in irb.

Comment: Also I tried making another script and running it 
`a = [%w(1 2 3)];
a.delete!("1")`

But I got NoMethodError... What gives?

Answer (score 5):

It's a common idiom. Bang methods modify object in-place, "normal" methods return a modified copy.

The `delete!` method call you're performing is against a string, not an array. And `String` does indeed have method `delete!`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-delete-21

Comment: However, `Array#delete` _does_ modify the array in place (and there is no bang version).